# Consolidate validation function

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, this

Hi trying to consolidate this validation function that checks 3 age inputs. At the moment it highlights the incorrect input and shows/hides an error message if the age is under 18.

How would I make the function run on all 3 inputs and stop repeating myself?

```
//Adult age validation
validateAdultAge0: function() {
    $('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
var inputVal = parseInt( $("input[name='adultAges[0]']").val());
if (inputVal < 18) {
    $("input[name='adultAges[0]']").css("border-color","red");
        });
},

validateAdultAge1: function() {
    $('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
var inputVal = parseInt( $("input[name='adultAges[1]']").val());
if (inputVal < 18) {
    $("input[name='adultAges[1]']").css("border-color","red");
        });
},

validateAdultAge2: function() {
    $('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
var inputVal = parseInt( $("input[name='adultAges[2]']").val());
if (inputVal < 18) {
    console.log ('fire');
    $("input[name='adultAges[2]']").css("border-color","red");
        });
}
```

The furthest I've gotten is:

```
validateAdultAges: function() {
    $('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
var inputVal = parseInt( $("input[name^='adultAges']").val());
if (inputVal < 18) {
    console.log('fire');
    $(this).find("input").css("border-color","red");
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be using a class (say `adultAges`) for inputs as:

```
validateAdultAges: function() {
    $('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
        $("input.adultAges").each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                inputVal = parseInt( $this.val(), 10);
            if (inputVal < 18) {
                $this.css("border-color","red");
            }
        });    
    });
}
```

Comment: had to change input.adultAges to "input[name^='adultAges']" but this worked! Thanks!!!